# Toggle between two C# checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox, toggle

Using C#, I am trying to create a relationship between two checkboxes:
1. `chk_PeelTrace` and 2. `chk_MoveTrace`,
where only one checkbox can be checked at a time, so that if `PeelTrace` starts as true, and I check `MoveTrace`, then `MoveTrace` should be checked while `PeelTrace` should become unchecked.

Importantly, however, it should be possible for both to be unchecked simultaneously. I have tried a number of different things; some of these alternatives are commented out in the example below.

No matter what I try, I haven't been able to get this working properly. I keep running into a System.StackOverflowException but am not sure why. Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this?

```
    private void chk_PeelTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////if (tracePeel)
        //if (chk_PeelTrace.CheckState.Equals(CheckState.Checked))
        if (chk_PeelTrace.Checked)
        {
            ////tracePeel = false;
            //chk_PeelTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_PeelTrace.Checked = !chk_PeelTrace.Checked;
            ////traceMove = false;
            //chk_MoveTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_MoveTrace.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ////traceMove = false;
            //chk_MoveTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_MoveTrace.Checked = false;
            ////tracePeel = true;
            //chk_PeelTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            chk_PeelTrace.Checked = true;       
        }
    }

    private void chk_MoveTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (chk_MoveTrace.Checked == true)
        ////if (traceMove)
        //if (chk_MoveTrace.CheckState.Equals(CheckState.Checked))
        if (chk_MoveTrace.Checked)
        {
            ////traceMove = false;
            //chk_MoveTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_MoveTrace.Checked = !chk_MoveTrace.Checked;
            ////tracePeel = false;
            //chk_PeelTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_PeelTrace.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ////tracePeel = false;
            //chk_PeelTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chk_PeelTrace.Checked = false;
            ////traceMove = true;
            //chk_MoveTrace.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            chk_MoveTrace.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You said; *only one checkbox can be active at a time*. For this scenario use a radio button instead of checkbox inside a groupbox.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just add some flag (boolean field) to disable handling of events caused by another handler's code.

```
private void chk_PeelTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (handleChecked)
    {
        handleChecked=false;
        // your handler code
        handleChecked=true;
    }
}

private void chk_MoveTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (handleChecked)
    {
        handleChecked=false;
        // your handler code
        handleChecked=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i have understood the question you want both to be false , but both should not be true at the same time , So how about trying this simple code below :

```
 private void chk_PeelTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chk_PeelTrace.Checked) 
        {
            chk_MoveTrace.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    private void chk_MoveTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chk_MoveTrace.Checked)
        {
            chk_PeelTrace.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

also this worked fine for me

Comment: @Andres : Hope you don't mind accepting it as an answer too .

Comment: You can do it by just click to the check box below my answer , it will get high-light to green once you accept it .